# Electromagnetic field confined inside a closed optical resonator

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, maxwell-equations

I am currently studying Maxwell's equations. Out of interest, I was reading the introduction to the textbook *The Quantum Theory of Light*, third edition, by Louden. When discussing the photon, the author says the following:

> The idea of the photon is most easily expressed for an electromagnetic field confined inside a closed optical resonator, or perfectly-reflecting cavity. The field excitations are then limited to an infinite discrete set of spatial modes determined by the boundary conditions at the cavity walls.

So does this mean that there is some form of Maxwell's equations that show that "the field excitations are limited to an infinite discrete set of spatial modes determined by the boundary conditions"? If so, then would someone please elaborate on this further (showing and explaining the mathematics) for the sake of clarity? Otherwise, what is the relevant equation that shows what the author is alluding to?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Possibly related: [Modeling the field inside a cavity resonator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282218/141502)

Comment: any optics textbook has the relevant derivations. See, e.g., the book by [Saleh](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471213748). You are looking for fabry-perot cavities or just simply a resonator. As light behaves as a wave, within a resonator you are only allowed to have standing waves which are phase multiples of the optical phase length of the cavity. The higher the finesse of the cavity (the closer to perfectly reflecting) the closer these modes become dirac delta like (as the photon lifetime inside the cavity tends to an infinite time and the interference becomes stronger)

Comment: @JoséAndrade I've got the 3rd edition of the Saleh textbook (currently studying). Which page is it? Also, feel free to post an answer if you want, so that I may award the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[Electromagnetic Wave Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation)** is what you are looking for, which is a kind of **[wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation)** that can be set up from Maxwell's equations. The solution of this equation for a perfectly-reflective **resonant cavity** (this is a **[Boundary Value Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem)**), produces the infinite discrete set of spatial modes mentioned. Searching for the terms bolded gives plenty of resources on methods and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate on or provide some resources regarding the the infinite discrete set of spatial modes? Which part of the Wikipedia articles specifically refers to this?

Comment: I didn't find an explicit derivation using EM equations in Saleh, so here's something else a quick search dug up:
http://people.duke.edu/~qhliu/ee271/chap8.pdf
This has a derivation of the modes for a rectangular and cylindrical cavity at the end. It builds on the information from rectangular and cylindrical waveguides, so you should probably read it all.